# Scatter plot for multiple variables on x axis

Tags: r, scatter-plot, categorical-data

I want to create a scatter plot for multiple variables defined in different columns. 
sample input:

```
df=structure(list(section = structure(1:6, .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e", "f"), class = "factor"), level = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 0L), math.av = c(83L, 67L, 76L, 56L, 72L, 76L), science.av = c(75L, 
76L, 82L, 72L, 82L, 68L), language.av = c(80L, 75L, 80L, 73L, 
85L, 70L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I want the x axis to be divided for each of the 3 different columns of the subjects, and the y axis to be representing their different values.

I have to group them in colors with another column as an indicator which in this case, according to the level

Comment: Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: Also, think about facetting instead, to make it less confusing

Comment: @FrancescoGrossetti updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with `dplyr` and `ggplot2`.

First, we need to pivot the data to be long instead of wide.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
long_df <- df %>% pivot_longer(-c(section,level))
```

Then we can graph a dotplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(long_df, aes(x=as.factor(name),y=value,fill=as.factor(level))) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y') +
  labs(x="Subject") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Level"))
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(section = structure(1:6, .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e", "f"), class = "factor"), level = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 0L), math.av = c(83L, 67L, 76L, 56L, 72L, 76L), science.av = c(75L, 
76L, 82L, 72L, 82L, 68L), language.av = c(80L, 75L, 80L, 73L, 
85L, 70L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```